# How to apply FAST on a set of points?

Tags: performance, opencv

I have obtained the contours in a image and I want apply FAST algorithm to detect feature points on the contour path.

How to apply FAST on a series of points rather that the entire image?

I assume that FAST when applied on these points will require the data from the image also.
I want to implement a function as below

```
    feature_points = getFAST(CvPoints Array_to_check, CvMat Image);
```

or

```
   feature_points =  getFAST(CvPoint Array_to_check, uchar* Image.data());
```

Comment: One method would be to compute FAST for the entire image, then only keep points which fall on the contour.

Comment: @Aurelius Thanks, that is one method. Expecting more solutions..

Comment: can't open OpenCV documentation at the moment. If FAST allows you to use a mask, you could draw a white region for each of your points on a black image and use that image as a mask (draw neighbordhood too if necessary).

Comment: Yes, that is possible. The concern is i will be passing a/the image for every contour, while only need to process few sets of points